# How to make GET parameters not prone to overriding?

Tags: php

Let's say I have an address http://example.org/articles/children/title. Now, mod_rewrite translates it into http://example.org?type=article&category=children&id=title.

Now, most users only read the first part, ignoring anything that's after question mark. And they should be safe to do so. But if someone links to me using http://example.org/articles/title?something=long_meaningless_string&type=adult&title=othertitle my app sees `$type == "adult"` when clicking reader believes he went to a children section.

Any safe and sure way to prevent abuse like that? It's especially problematic with well known CMS systems, where attacker knows get variable names and can use it to hit site's reputation.

Comment: So you want to send your visitors to the children's section, and only when they have type=adult in their query string AND that query string section is clearly visible to the user, they should be sent to the adult section?

Comment: @Geier I want the first variable from URL to be interpreted, not the last - because it's usually what user thinks is interpreted. For example to only show user the category he thinks he clearly sees, yes, but that's only an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to rename your keys, so that they have a [] at the end, like so:

http://example.org?type[]=article&category[]=children&id[]=title

This will result in a $_GET-Array like this:

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => article
        )

    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => children
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => title
        )

)
```

If someone appends more type[]-Entries to the query-String as in `http://example.org?type[]=article&category[]=children&type[]=adult`, it will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => article
            [1] => adult
        )

    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => children
        )

)
```

So you can still get the first entry.

---

If you don't want to append the `[]` to your keys, you would have to parse the Query-String, which you can get via `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Determine a canonical URI for each page. When the page is requested, check if the URI matches the canonical one. If it doesn't, issue a 301 redirect. (e.g. [like this](https://github.com/dorward/Recall/blob/master/lib/Recall/Controller/Blog.pm#L285) (although that isn't PHP)).

Comment: Actually, that would direct reader to an adult section anyway, right? And I just want to give him what he expects (category children in this example) and discard all the rest.

Comment: You can use whatever rules you like to make that determination, so it wouldn't necessarily redirect to the adult section.